# Function in Mongo Shell. MongoshUnimplementedError: Unable to handle 'this' keyword outside of method definition

Tags: mongodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogzUp.png)

```
var mapFunc = function() {
    for(i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++){
        var student = this.students[i];
 
        // Emit gets 2 arguments being the key on which you want to group the 
        // data and the data itself
        emit(student.fName + " " + student.lName, 1);
    }
};
```

MongoshUnimplementedError: Unable to handle 'this' keyword outside of method definition
What should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried this query directly in the mongo console?

Comment: @Wojtek-x did you find a solution?